# String conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 Big endian is failing (using C, C++ language)

Tags: c++, c, utf-8, glib, utf-16

I am using g_convert() glib function to convert utf-8 string to utf-16 big endian string. The conversion is failing.  We are getting an error saying "conversion is not supported"

Could someone give a clue to overcome this issue.

Thanks

Following is the piece of code used to convert string from UTF-8. to UTF16 Bigendian

```
unsigned short *result_str;

gsize bytes_read, bytes_written;

gssize len = 0;

GError *error = NULL;

result_str = (unsigned short *)g_convert("text data", len, "UTF-16BE", "UTF-8", &bytes_read, &bytes_written, &error);
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with it, but as a practical solution, how about converting to little endian utf-16 and then just byte-swapping? Or, look up utf-8 encoding algorithms e.g. Wikipedia. Sometimes DIY is easier than getting someone else's code to work. :-)

Comment: Could you post a minimal piece of code which shows the problem that you're having? There are a lot of possible causes of the problems, and having a small piece of code which displays the problem helps to eliminate some possibilities.

Comment: I always wonder about these folks who want to convert *into* UTF-16.  You’d think that most of them want to go the other way: after all, how many web pages do you see in UTF-8?  Now how many in UTF-16?  '

Answer (score 3):

You `len` is 0. The GLib [manual](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html#g-convert) says that `len` must be -1 for a NULL-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

g_convert uses iconv underneath the covers.

On my machine using cygwim I can do

```
iconv -l
```

which lists the supported encodings and UTF-16BE does appear in the list however:-

```
$ iconv -l | grep BE
UCS-2BE UNICODE-1-1 UNICODEBIG CSUNICODE11
UCS-4BE
UTF-16BE
UTF-32BE

James@XPL3KWK28 ~
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF16-BE
iconv: conversion to UTF16-BE unsupported
iconv: try 'iconv -l' to get the list of supported encodings
```

as you can see it does not support the conversion to or from UTF-8.

You probably need to do this in two stages UTF-8 to UTF-16 then UTF-16 to UTF-16BE.

Comment: iconv -l | grep BE
EBCDIC-BE//
EBCDIC-CP-BE//
UCS-2BE//
UCS-4BE//
UTF-16BE//
UTF-32BE//
UTF16BE//
UTF32BE//

Comment: Its supporting conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16BE. But not sure why am I getting that error..

Comment: The individual code pages may be supported, but the conversion from any particular code page to another is not nessecerily supported.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `UTF-16BE` is not supported by `g_convert` (based on the error message). It's trivial to convert UTF-8 into UTF-16BE though (no tables or other garbage like that) -- you can do that transformation yourself.

You might also want to check if `UTF-16` is supported and do your own byte swapping if necessary. But I do not believe `g_convert` supports `UTF-16` either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system does not support that conversion. (This error means that iconv() returned EINVAL.)

On my Linux system it does appear to be supported:

```
echo "Hello" | iconv --from-code UTF-16BE --to-code UTF-8
```

(obviously "Hello" is not a valid UTF-16 string, but it does get converted to something, so the actual conversion seems to be supported)

See if you have UTF-16BE in "iconv --list"

In this particular case your simplest solution might be to just use g_utf8_to_utf16():
http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-to-utf16

You can easily do your own byteswap, untested code:

```
if (G_BYTE_ORDER != G_BIG_ENDIAN) {
  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    result_str[i] = GUINT16_TO_BE(result_str[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: "iconv --list" has UTF-16BE on my system

Comment: There are actually 2: UTF-16BE, UTF16BE. Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: I doubt there's a difference in the two spellings. Perhaps iconv supports the encoding but not conversion from UTF-8, or perhaps there's something else wrong with your glib or C library installation.

Comment: if you post a small compilable test case people could try it on their systems and let you know if this problem is specific to your system.